# In Entity Framework & C#, what is the better way to query?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I am working on C# project which is implemented using Entity Framework. Consider following example, when we apply filters, sorting etc., it applies on complete data which is logical and understandable.

```
ObjectContext.table.Where(conditions).OrderBy(column).AsPagination(pageNumber,totalRows);
```

BUT it will all be executed by C# not SQL Server. Right?

If yes, then is there more efficient way to query? Because, I think its the duty of SQL Server.

Comment: Depend on what is ObjectContext. But looks like is execute on DB. And looks good to me.

Comment: No. LINQ, and `IQueryable`, allows Entity Framework to understand expressions and pass them to SQL, so that's what it does. Barring explicitly downloading data (`ToList()`, etc.), your queries will be performed against the SQL Server, and only relevant data will be transmitted.

Comment: To add to Matthew Haugen's comment: All operations that return an IQueryable or IGrouping respectively, will NOT be executed (not even a list of IQueryables), until you iterate over the objects, best by calling ToList(). Then the whole IQueryable object before will be translated to an SQL query, this will be executed on your database and then manifested to a list of objects.

Comment: @matthew-haugen: So it will pass single expression to SQL against above statement?

Comment: i think you have to read and understand the IQueryable interface this is a good tutorial http://blog.falafel.com/understanding-ienumerable-iqueryable-c/

Comment: Like others have said, it will be executed on the database.  Assuming you're using DbContext, you can do something like `myContext.Database.Log = x => MessageBox.Show(x);` and you'll see what SQL is actually being executed.